# Ensure dialog is removed from history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please see code at http://cyclestreets.darkgreener.com/location/ - if necessary, go to a London, UK location to see some markers)

When you click on a marker, a jQuery mobile dialog opens.

If you then follow the 'Full link to photo page', then click Back, the page attempts to reload the dialog.

Is there any way I can remove the dialog from the history model altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know this is a known bug in JQuery Mobile:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2232

Comment: Hmm the examples here show the Dialog not being tracked in history, Does this not work? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Disable execution of this dialog when navigate back from particular page should solve your issue.